# Simple MySQL Query - Change table format around

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fairly sure this is a fairly easy answer but the answer is completely slipping my mind.

I have a database table that is currently formatted like:

```
event_id | elem_id | value
   1          1      Value 1
   1          2      Value 2
   2          1      Value 3
   2          2      Value 4
```

Both event_id and elem_id are undetermined numbers and have infinite possibilities.

How would I query it for example based on event_id 1 to get the data to be formatted as such:

```
event_id |    1    |     2
   1       Value 1    Value 2
```

Knowing that elem_id is a number >= n so potentially there could be 50 elem_id yet I  still need the data in that format.

Like I said I can't for the life of me figure out the query to assemble it that way. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Unlike some other RDBMS, MySQL doesn't have native support for pivoting operations of this sort (by design, as the developers feel such things belong more appropriately in the presentation layer).  Try performing these manipulations in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
SELECT 
    `event_id`, 
    (SELECT t2.`value` FROM table t2 WHERE t2.`event_id` = t1.`event_id` AND t2.`elem_id` = 1), 
    (SELECT t3.`value` FROM table t3 WHERE t3.`event_id` = t1.`event_id` AND t3.`elem_id` = 2) 
FROM `table` t1 GROUP BY `event_id`;
```

Also you can use different way, and get elem_ids and values in comma-separated format in two cells

```
SELECT `event_id`, GROUP_CONCAT(`elem_id`), GROUP_CONCAT(`value`) FROM `table` GROUP BY `event_id`;
```

and you can change separator with following syntax: `GROUP_CONCAT(field SEPARATOR '::')`

Comment: also you can replace subqueryes with JOIN